# Mathematica Version 11.0.1 Strange Result from NSolve (Linux)

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

I recently got an update to Mathematica Version 11.0.1 (Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64, RHEL 7.2, Lustre 2.5.42.8.ddn5), and run some test routines to check, if my Mathematica packages are still compatible with the newest version. During the test, I encountered the following strange result:

```
In[1]:= foc=(433 - 2*q[4])/10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

        433 - 2 q[4]
Out[1]= ------------
            10

In[2]:= NSolve[foc==0,q[4]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Out[2]= {{}}

In[3]:= Solve[foc==0,q[4]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

                  433
Out[3]= {{q[4] -> ---}}
                   2
```

In contrast, if I set, for instance,

```
In[10]:= NSolve[433/10==2/10*q[4],q[4]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

Out[10]= {{q[4] -> 216.5}}
```

No effect, when I change $q[4]$ simply to $x$.

However, under Mathematica Version 10.3.1 I get the correct result

```
In[2]:= NSolve[foc==0,q[4]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Out[2]= {{q[4] -> 216.5}}
```

Can anybody reproduce the above strange result? How to fix it?

Comment: I can reproduce it on Mac too, setting `WorkingPrecision -> \[Infinity]` fixes this. Also changing any number to real or specifying the `Reals` domain.

Comment: A better bug representation would be just `NSolve[2 x == 0, x]`

Comment: This is a bug that will be fixed in the 11.1 release. More details in my post [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/932742).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am running V11.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite). I can confirm that something strange is going on with `NSolve` with a much simpler example than the one given in the question.

```
NSolve[4 x - 3 == 0, x]
```

`{{x -> 0.75}}`

However, neither of the following work

```
NSolve[(4 x - 3)/2 == 0, x]
```

`{{}}`

and

```
NSolve[(4 x - 3)/2. == 0, x]
```

`{{}}`

while all these work.

```
NSolve[Expand[(4. x - 3)/2] == 0, x]
```

`{{x -> 0.75}}`

```
NSolve[Expand[(4 x - 3)/2.] == 0, x]
```

`{{x -> 0.75}}`

```
NSolve[(4 x - 3)/2 == 0., x]
```

`{{x -> 0.75}}`

```
NSolve[(4 x - 3)/2 == 0, x, Reals]
```

`{{x -> 0.75}}`

I say it looks like a bug, walks like a bug, and quacks like a bug, so let's call it a bug.

#### Update

I reported this issue to Wolfram tech support and received a reply. I quote the relevant portions thereof.

> I have confirmed the behavior you are observing with NSolve not being able to find the roots in the example you have provided. I have filed a report with our developers regarding this issue and include the example you have provided. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.